# Port forward from kubernetes pod to local container

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding

I need to connect a service running in a local container inside Docker on my machine to a database that's running on a Kubernetes cluster.

Everything I found on port forwarding allowed me to connect my machine to the cluster, but not the local container to the cluster (unless I install kubectl on my container, which I cannot do).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You will want to follow [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20227), although running something like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) in the container may get you where you want to go, as it has a bazillion options (and is secretly how kubelet does port forwarding under the covers)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.telepresence.io/ is what you're looking for. It will hook into the cluster network like a VPN and patch the services so traffic will get routed through the tunnel.